# How are elements in the head section of a page inherited by a second one called through Ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have two HTML pages. The first one contains a form which is submitted to the second one through an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request. This way, as soon as the user submits the form, the second page is displayed at the bottom of the form without reloading.

At the moment my first page is a complete HTML document (head with *link* and *script* elements + body), while the second page contains just php code (no *html*, *head*, *body* structure). Practically speaking I treated the second page as if it were "included" in the first one.

The problem comes when I want to display [this slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax) using jQuery UI in the second page.

I add jQuery UI in the head section of the first page:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 1,
            max: 10,
            value: 2,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
    </script>
```

When I try to display the slider in the second page, it is not displayed correctly. Here is the code I use in the body section:

```
  <p>
    <label for="amount">Minimum number of bedrooms:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
</p>
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>
```

However, if I try the same code in the body section of the first page, they slider is displayed perfectly.

Therefore my question is... How are the *link* and *script* elements in the head section of a page inherited by a second one called through Ajax?

Should the second page be also a complete HTML document where I include my *script* and *link* elements in the head section?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Need to see the javascript/jQuery that loads the extra HTML into the page. That's where the solution lies.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the Javascript of the first page will only be aware of the DOM content at the time that page has completed loading.

New content loaded after that won't be recognised.

To address this, you can either load the second page as a complete HTML page including all headers and scripts and so on.

Or alternatively, still load the second page as the partial page that you currently have, but just include the extra 'script' and 'link' sections at the top of the partial page to ensure  that they are applied to the context of the newly loaded DOM content.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "inheritance" between the two documents. JavaScript is executed when encountered what happens in the two scenarios you describe is that when you have the JS in the head it's executed before the loading of the second page completes. By chance when you embed it as part of the body the second page is loaded and the html is inserted into the dom of the first page before the slider specific code is executed which is way it works.

You will need to include the splider specific code into the success handler of the ajax call. Something similar to the code below

```
$.ajax({
   url: urlOfSecondPage,
   success : function() {
        $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 1,
            max: 10,
            value: 2,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
    }
});
```

Alternatively insert the original JS as part of the second page.